# Unable to connect with Mqtt using wss protocol

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, mqtt, flutter-dependencies

I want to connect mqtt using wss protocol.

What have I tried ->

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_server_client.dart';

final client = MqttServerClient('wss://myServer.com/mqtt', '');

Future<int> main() async {
client.useWebSocket = true;
client.port = 8083;
client.logging(on: true);
client.keepAlivePeriod = 20;
client.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
client.onConnected = onConnected;
client.onSubscribed = onSubscribed;
client.pongCallback = pong;
final connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
  .withClientIdentifier('Mqtt_MyClientUniqueId')
  .keepAliveFor(20) 
  .withWillTopic('willtopic') 
  .withWillMessage('My Will message')
  .startClean() 
  .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connecting....');
client.connectionMessage = connMess;
try {
await client.connect();
} on NoConnectionException catch (e) {
print('EXAMPLE::client exception - $e');
client.disconnect();
} on SocketException catch (e) {
print('EXAMPLE::socket exception - $e');
client.disconnect();
}

/// Check we are connected
if (client.connectionStatus.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connected');
} else {
print(
    'EXAMPLE::ERROR Mosquitto client connection failed - disconnecting, status is         
            ${client.connectionStatus}');
 client.disconnect();
 exit(-1);
 }
 print('EXAMPLE::Subscribing to the test/lol topic');
 const topic = 'test/lol';
 client.subscribe(topic, MqttQos.atMostOnce);
 client.updates.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>> c) {
 final MqttPublishMessage recMess = c[0].payload;
 final pt =
 MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message);
 print(
    'EXAMPLE::Change notification:: topic is <${c[0].topic}>, payload is <-- $pt -->');
  print('');
  });
  client.published.listen((MqttPublishMessage message) {
  print(
    'EXAMPLE::Published notification:: topic is ${message.variableHeader.topicName}, with      Qos ${message.header.qos}');
});
const pubTopic = 'Dart/Mqtt_client/testtopic';
final builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
builder.addString('Hello from mqtt_client');
print('EXAMPLE::Subscribing to the Dart/Mqtt_client/testtopic topic');
client.subscribe(pubTopic, MqttQos.exactlyOnce);
print('EXAMPLE::Publishing our topic');
client.publishMessage(pubTopic, MqttQos.exactlyOnce, builder.payload);
print('EXAMPLE::Sleeping....');
await MqttUtilities.asyncSleep(120);
print('EXAMPLE::Unsubscribing');
client.unsubscribe(topic);
await MqttUtilities.asyncSleep(2);
print('EXAMPLE::Disconnecting');
client.disconnect();
return 0;
}
void onSubscribed(String topic) {
print('EXAMPLE::Subscription confirmed for topic $topic');
}

void onDisconnected() {
print('EXAMPLE::OnDisconnected client callback - Client disconnection');
if (client.connectionStatus.disconnectionOrigin ==
  MqttDisconnectionOrigin.solicited) {
print('EXAMPLE::OnDisconnected callback is solicited, this is correct');
}
exit(-1);
}
void onConnected() {
print(
  'EXAMPLE::OnConnected client callback - Client connection was sucessful');
}
void pong() {
print('EXAMPLE::Ping response client callback invoked');
}
```

and I get below response in logs

```
EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connecting....
I/flutter (17123): 1-2021-01-27 15:15:27.085221 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::connect - server wss://myServer.com/mqtt, port 1883
I/flutter (17123): 1-2021-01-27 15:15:27.103638 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect entered
I/flutter (17123): 1-2021-01-27 15:15:27.104865 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - initiating connection try 0, auto reconnect in progress false
I/flutter (17123): 1-2021-01-27 15:15:27.107198 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - websocket selected
I/flutter (17123): 1-2021-01-27 15:15:27.110498 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - calling connect
I/flutter (17123): 1-2021-01-27 15:15:27.117350 -- MqttWsConnection::connect - entered
I/flutter (17123): 1-2021-01-27 15:15:27.168054 -- MqttWsConnection::connect - WS URL is wss://myServer.com:1883/mqtt, protocols are [mqtt, mqttv3.1, mqttv3.11]
I/flutter (17123): 1-2021-01-27 15:17:37.221102 -- MqttConnectionBase::_onError - calling disconnected callback
I/flutter (17123): EXAMPLE::socket exception - SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = myServer.com, port = 32892
I/flutter (17123): 1-2021-01-27 15:17:37.243831 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::disconnect - entered
I/flutter (17123): 1-2021-01-27 15:17:37.245454 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_performConnectionDisconnect entered
I/flutter (17123): EXAMPLE::OnDisconnected client callback - Client disconnection
```

Comment: The logs don't match your code. The logs show trying to connect to port 1883 with secure websockets, under normal configuration port 1883 would be native MQTT without TLS. The code shows port 8083. Please update the question with details of your broker and how you've configured it.

Answer (score 1):

**it made me tired but this code is working
please don't 'secure = true'
this is set to 'web socket base'**

```
    class MqttConnection {
  static MqttConnection? _mqttConnection;
  static MqttServerClient? _mqttClient;
 MqttConnection._() {
    _mqttClient =
        MqttServerClient("wss://your domain/", "flutter_client");
    _mqttClient!.port = 9001;
    _mqttClient!.keepAlivePeriod = 20;
    _mqttClient!.autoReconnect = true;
    _mqttClient!.onConnected = _mqttConnected;
    _mqttClient!.onDisconnected = _mqttDisconnected;
    _mqttClient!.useWebSocket = true;
    _mqttClient!.logging(on: true);
  }

  static MqttConnection getInstanse() {
    if (_mqttConnection != null) return _mqttConnection!;
    if (_mqttConnection == null) _mqttConnection = MqttConnection._();
    return _mqttConnection!;
  }

  Future connectMqtt() async {
    final MqttConnectMessage connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
        .authenticateAs(ApiConstant.mqttUser, ApiConstant.mqttPassword)
        .withClientIdentifier((await _getDeviceId())!)
        .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce)
        .startClean();
    _mqttClient!.connectionMessage = connMess;
    _mqttClient!.securityContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(
        (await rootBundle.load("assets/cert/bundle.crt")).buffer.asUint8List());
    var connection = await _mqttClient!.connect();
    isConnect = connection!.state == MqttConnectionState.connected;
    _mqttClient!.updates!.listen(mqttEventRecived);
  }

  Function? callback;
  bool isConnect = false;
  bool tryToConnect = true;

  void stopMqtt() {
    tryToConnect = false;
    _mqttClient!.disconnect();
    isConnect = false;
  }

  subscribeTopics(List<String> topics) async {
    if (!isConnect) {
      await connectMqtt();
    }
    for (var topic in topics) {
      _mqttClient!.subscribe(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
    }
  }

  unSubscribeTopics(List<String> topics) {
    for (var topic in topics) {
      _mqttClient!.unsubscribe(topic);
    }
  }

  void _mqttConnected() {
    print("connected");
    isConnect = true;
  }

  void _mqttDisconnected() {
    isConnect = false;
  }

  Future<void> mqttEventRecived(event) async {
    if (callback != null) {
     
    }
  }
}
```